# Foreign Key в H2

Tags: sql, h2

Есть три таблицы. Абоненты, Услуги и Счета. Пытаюсь связать таблицы Абоненты и Услуги через Счета с помощью Foreign Key.

#### Пример:

```
ABONENTS
ID | PHONE | NAME | SURNAME | ADDRESS | ...
1  | 12345 | Eric | Helm    | Address | ...

SERVICES
ID | TITLE    | COST | ...
1  | Internet | 1000 | ...

BILLS
ID | ABONENT_ID | SERVICE_ID | SUMM | ...

Где ABONENT_ID и SERVICE_ID - FOREIGN KEY
```

Делаю так:

```
CREATE TABLE ATS.BILLS(ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
ABONENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ATS.ABONENTS(ID),
SERVICE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ATS.SERVICES(ID),
LAST_PAYMENT DATE, NEXT_PAYMENT DATE, PAYMENT_STATUS BOOLEAN);
```

Пламенный ответ от H2:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE ATS.BILLS(ID INTEGER NOT NULL
AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, ABONENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN[*] KEY
REFERENCES ATS.ABONENTS(ID), SERVICE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY
REFERENCES ATS.SERVICES(ID), LAST_PAYMENT DATE, NEXT_PAYMENT DATE,
PAYMENT_STATUS BOOLEAN)"; expected "AS, DEFAULT, GENERATED, NOT, NULL,
AUTO_INCREMENT, BIGSERIAL, SERIAL, IDENTITY, NULL_TO_DEFAULT, SEQUENCE,
SELECTIVITY, COMMENT, CONSTRAINT, PRIMARY, UNIQUE, NOT, NULL, CHECK,
REFERENCES, ,, )";
SQL statement: CREATE TABLE ATS.BILLS(ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
PRIMARY KEY, ABONENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES
ATS.ABONENTS(ID), SERVICE_ID INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES
ATS.SERVICES(ID), LAST_PAYMENT DATE, NEXT_PAYMENT DATE, PAYMENT_STATUS
BOOLEAN) [42001-188] 42001/42001
```

Веб-приложение на Java, СУБД H2 в embedded-режиме. И еще один вопрос. Если
у абонента будет несколько услуг то таблица Счета станет ненормализованной.
Как это все можно грамотно организовать? SQL изучаю паралельно с этим
проектом и конечно же в проектировании базы данных опыта вообще нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Попробуйте убрать слова FOREIGN KEY, т.е. оставить только REFERENCES.
2. Что вы понимаете под словами "ненормализованная"?

Comment: Огромное спасибо, заработало) Почему-то в официальной документации на нашел этого уточнения. Насчет ненормализованности: Допустим есть один абонент и у него три услуги. Теперь в таблице СЧЕТА получается три записи на каждую услугу и соответственно ABONENTS_ID повторяется три раза. Это же ведь ненормализованность, не так ли?

Comment: >Это же ведь ненормализованность, не так ли?

Нет. Это как раз нормализованность. Ненормализованность была бы, если бы вы в таблице абонентов хранили столбцы их счетов - по столбцу на счет. 
Впрочем, это тренд в NoSQL-ных базах.